# Python's ipdb behaves differently with 'next' vs 'continue'

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

I'm looking for potential causes of strange behaviour.

The code where I observed this has since been replaced. Moreover, restoring to the commit where it happened now produces different results.

I'm worried that this was a symptom of something else which might come back later and bite me.

The issue was that the app would crash on this simple line:

```
if self.user.user_type in [0,1]:
```

saying list index out of range.

Putting a `ipdb.set_trace` right before that line, and running command "`p self.user.user_type`" would correctly print 0.

Typing "`next`" would work. Typing "`continue`" would crash, saying `list index out of range`.

And maybe 1/10 attempts, "`continue`" would work, but would crash later on an unrelated line, but still show me the line above as the cause of the error.

Continually hitting "`next`" would also eventually crash on that other unrelated line, but also show the original "`if self.user.user_type in [0,1]:`" as the source of the error.

I haven't tried updating ipdb and ipython when I first ran into this, but reverting to that commit now after having updated both still shows incorrect line in the traceback after crashing on the unrelated line. The crashing on the innocent line no longer occurs.

I've dealt with my fair share of memory corruption bugs in C, but I'm relatively new to python, and have no idea what could possibly cause this.

There's nothing too crazy going on in the app, it's just an http request, handled by `Tornado`, that then fires up my handler class, which is where this was happening.

No multithreading going on either.

Comment: what was `self.user.user_type`?

Comment: can you show actual traceback messages or the code you were using?

Comment: getting an example value of `self.user.user_type` is critical in answering this problem. I wouldn't expect this code to create such crashes.

Comment: self.user.user_type = 0

Comment: Evidenced by the print command I typed into ipdb right before proceeding. Also it's only ever set to 0, 1, or 2, in exactly one place, when the user is created.

I'm off for the weekend so I can't show any code at the time.

I don't expect any specific answers, maybe just some pointers in the right direction. I know in C a buffer overflow can cause all sorts of weird fun things for you. Is there anything similar in python? How hard is it to introduce some memory corruption?

Or maybe ipdb itself is buggy (unlikely, I know)?